# uploading a base64 image to firebase storage error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have this function that uses cordova camera plugin to pick image inside my phones photo library, converts it to base64 then upload it to firebase.. i followed the firebse documentation with regards to uploading a base64 image to the firebase storage.. unfortunately, it throws an error about payload ..
can someone help ?

```
$scope.changeImage=function(){

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    var options = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 500,
      targetHeight: 500,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
   $scope.cbuddyURL=imageData;
   var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('sample');
   var upload=storageRef.putString(imageData,'base64').then(function(){
      console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
   })
    }, function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });



  }, false);
}
```

Comment: it would be wise to include what the error prints, exactly as it is

Comment: i can't really see the error since it's on the phone .. and i can't do it on the browser because cordova camera plugin only works in a phone

Comment: you can debug the app while running on the device of course.